# How to add users in Azure subscription using az commands

Tags: azure, azure-cli

How to add user as a contributor using Az commands ?

I am aware using portal.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/add-change-subscription-administrator#to-assign-a-user-as-an-administrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the `az role assignment create` command:

```
az role assignment create --assignee user@e.mail --role Owner --scope /subscriptions/<subscription id>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below Microsoft document. This have explained all the steps in detail

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-cli